# How come a new-expression can correctly produce the pointer type, even though it should return void*?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, void-pointers, new-expression

We know that `void*` holds no information regarding the actual type of the data it points to. However, from cppreference on [`new` and `new[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) we know that those operators return `void*`. How come, then, given:

```
auto x = new int{};
```

knowing that the `new` operator should return `void*`, `x` is deduced to be of a type `int*`, not `void*`?

Consider yet another example:

```
struct foo {
    static void* operator new(std::size_t n) {
        std::cout << "new called!\n";
        return ::new char[n];
    }
};
```

let's add some **T**ype**D**isplayer:

```
template <typename T>
struct TD;
```

and the test code:

```
int main() {
    auto x = new foo{};

    TD<decltype(x)>{};
}
```

The code fails to compile with error indicating that `decltype(x)` is `foo*`. If we comment out the last line of `main`, we will know that our, `void*`-returning operator will be called due to `new called!` being printed.

Comment: Aren't you mixing `new` and `operator new`? These are different things.

Comment: @Evg probably. To be honest, I've never undertood the details there. So the *new expression* would return an appropriate pointer but internally use `operator new` to allocate the space?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy to confuse the `new` keyword with the operator `new`, but they're two different things. When you write a memory allocation function, its name is `operator new` and it does, as you say, return `void*`. But you don't ordinarily call that operator directly; instead, you create a new object with the `new` keyword. The **compiler** understands that keyword; it calls `operator new` to get memory for the object (or objects, for array `new`) that's being created and does whatever initialization is appropriate. The type of the result of that expression is a pointer to the type being created.

So, in the code

```
auto x = new int{};
```

the type of the expression `new int{}` is `int*`, so the deduced type for `x` is also `int*`.

Comment: Stellar, so all the problems came from my inability to corretly distinguish between `new` and `operator new`. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can, thank you.

Comment: And, in case it isn't obvious, the same thing applies to `delete` and `operator delete`.